# JavaMail Monitoring For New Messages

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a program that is supposed to monitor our Dovecot IMAP Server, and receive and process any new messages sent by Server. The problem I am having is, that the message gets processed multiple times i.e. Dovecot sends notification for the same message multiple times.

Below are the tricks I have tried.

1. Attaching a listener to folder. Sleeping and getting message count infinitely. After processing a message marking it as seen. This doesn't work because the server doesn't update the *seen* flag on its side quick enough, so reprocessing occurs.
2. Attaching a listener to folder. Idling infinitely. After processing a message marking it as *deleted*. In `messagesAdded` after looping through all messages and marking them as deleted, expunge the folder, close the folder and reopen the folder. Result is it doesn't process all the messages and also deletes in actual mbox files don't occur and also reprocessing occurs.
3. Attaching a listener to folder. Sleeping and idling infinitely. After processing a message marking it as *deleted*. In `messagesAdded` after looping through all messages and marking them as deleted, expunge the folder. Result is reprocessing occurs sometimes.

What else can I try? Below is the excerpt of the 3rd use case described above which is what I tried most recently. Below method runs in a daemon thread spawned from main thread.

```
private static void listenMessages() {
        try {
            // Add messageCountListener to listen for new messages
            _messageListener = new MessageCountAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
                    Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();

                    // Send new messages to specified users
                    for (Message msg : msgs) {
                        try {
                            //
                            // Collect the whole message. Check if the
                            // DiscussionId has been set in the Header.
                            //

                            if(msg.isExpunged()) {
                                log.warn("Message is expunged, continue");
                                continue;
                            }

                            String sContents = null;
                            try {
                                log.info(msg.getSubject().toString());
                                sContents = getText(msg);
                            } catch(MessageRemovedException mo) {
                                log.warn("Message has already been processed and expunged, continue");
                            }

                            boolean bCollaborationService = isCollaborationService(sContents);

                            if (bCollaborationService) {
                                dispatchMessage(((InternetAddress) msg.getFrom()[0]).getAddress(), msg.getReceivedDate().getTime(), sContents);
                            }
                            msg.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
                        } catch (IOException ioex) {
                            log.error(ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
                            log.error(mex.getMessage(), mex);
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        _folder.expunge();
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        log.error("Error Deleting Messages", e);
                    }
                }
            };
            _folder.addMessageCountListener(_messageListener);

            // Check mail once in "freq" MILLIseconds
            int freq = 20000;

            while (_messageListener != null) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(freq); // sleep for freq milliseconds
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
                    log.error("I have been interrrupted from MailRouter "
                            + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                _folder.idle();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Exception Occuered: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell if your problems are related to quirks of Dovecot, or the way you're handling messages...

Is your message handling single-threaded?  If so, isn't it sufficient to keep track of the highest message number or message UID that you've processed?

Are you worried about what happens if your message processing application crashes while in the middle of processing messages?

We probably need to understand more of your requirements to determine the best way to proceed.

Comment: It worked out. I had to turn off Dovecot config's mbox_lazy_writes.